# vbscript need to detect drive letter and ask for user input

Tags: windows, vbscript

I already have the script that ask user input to install the file "install1.exe" to "install6.exe" with default drive letter path D:\, I have another drive can get the drive letter like "C:", not sure how to integrate

First I need to have drive letter check to confirm the computer have drive D physical local disk (not cdrom), if yes prompt user confirm to proceed
 or user can click no to enter a drive letter, the drive letter also need to update on current install script {D}:\temp\install1.exe

## drive letter script

```
Dim query 
Dim objWMI 
Dim diskDrives 
Dim diskDrive 
Dim partitions 
Dim partition ' will contain the drive & partition numbers
Dim logicalDisks 
Dim logicalDisk ' will contain the drive letter

Set objWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
Set diskDrives = objWMI.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive") ' First get out the physical drives
For Each diskDrive In diskDrives 
    query = "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID='" + diskDrive.DeviceID + "'} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition" ' link the 
physical drives to the partitions
    Set partitions = objWMI.ExecQuery(query) 
    For Each partition In partitions 
        query = "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID='" + partition.DeviceID + "'} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition"  ' link 
the partitions to the logical disks 
        Set logicalDisks = objWMI.ExecQuery (query) 
        For Each logicalDisk In logicalDisks      
'            Wscript.Echo logicalDisk.DeviceID & " - " & partition.Caption
Wscript.Echo logicalDisk.DeviceID
'else
        Next
    Next 
Next
```

## Install script

```
Dim objShell
Dim Message, result
Dim Title, Text1, Text2

' Define dialog box variables.
Message = "Please enter a path"                  
Title = "Install Started"
Text1 = "Install Cancelled"
Text2 = "You entered value is incorrect, please select from 1,2,3,4,5 or 6" & vbCrLf
result = InputBox("Please select the by number"&  Chr(13) & "A" &  Chr(13) & "B" &  Chr(13) & "C" &  Chr(13) & "D" &  Chr(13) & "E" &  Chr(13) & "F", Title, "Please enter the number", 100, 100)
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
' Evaluate the user input.
If result = "" Then    ' Canceled by the user
    WScript.Echo Text1
ElseIf result = "1" Then   
    objShell.Run("7z.exe x temp.7z -oD:\ -bd -y")
wscript.sleep (3000)
        objShell.Run("D:\temp\install1.exe")
wscript.sleep (150000)
wScript.Echo "install Completed"
ElseIf result = "2" Then   
......
......
......
Else 
    WScript.Echo Text2 & result 
End If
wscript.quit
```

thank you

Comment: So...what's your question?

Comment: Hi, I need the vbscript to do the following, thanks


First I need to have drive letter check to confirm the computer have drive D physical local disk (not cdrom), if yes prompt user confirm to proceed or user can click no to enter a drive letter, the drive letter also need to update on current install script {D}:\temp\install1.exe

Comment: Then why don't you try it on your own?  This site isn't about us giving you code, it's about helping you solve targeted, specific problems you're having.  You need to attempt to finish the code on your own.

Comment: I did tried many times but not able get the result

Comment: You need to show evidence of that, and evidence of what you researched, explaining how/why it didn't help you.  Please read this before continuing:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I totally appreciate your comment

Comment: You can find it easily with a little *googling*..hint: the key is `DriveType`